# Why is there an "original research" flag on my answer to the shooting question?

Tags: discussion

Can someone explain this, please? My answer references the tables from which the calculation is made. Anybody could go and repeat the calculation, so it is verifiable and replicable. The tables are from Wikipedia, and mostly well referenced. The calculation is completely repeatable by anyone who cares to try.

Comment: The root problem here seems to be that the question itself is seen as controversial / ill-defined in some way - I suspect hashing that out first is a prerequisite to evaluating the answers. As such, I'm directing the discussion toward Oddthinking's question regarding the question.